# Stack Exchange websites with the HTML5 History API

Tags: feature-request

Not sure if this is the right place, but I've made a little screencast of what Stack Overflow looks like when it uses the HTML5 History API: http://vimeo.com/22396598

You can try it out yourself by using the following bookmark: https://gist.github.com/919358

For a little background info. Currently the Stack Exchange sites do not use the HTML5 History API and use the HTML4 hashchange functionality on the user profiles. Hashes are not ideal as they cause double loads when initially loading a page with a hashed url, are not acessible by js-disabled users and search engines, and cause duplicate urls for the same content. The HTML5 History API solves these problems by allowing you to modify the URL directly. [More info](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling).

So what do you think? Is this an improvement that the Stack Exchange team would be willing to look into?

Comment: Not my cup of tea, but do [all supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/71208#71208) understand this?

Comment: Correct. For html4 browsers it will use the hashchange functionality. Though that still has a few issues (refer to that more info link) so for HTML4 browsers it's better to disable this upgrade. The thing is it gracefully upgrades, so if you choose not to support html4 browsers it will work just like normal.